# Inserting an indexed string into the 1st position of each pair in a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, insert

> How do I insert "Z" and then a number going from 1 to end (without space) in a list?

I have the following list:

**Input:**

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

**Output:**

```
{Z1, 1, 1}, {Z2, 2, 1},{Z3, 3, 1}...
```

I have tried using the commando `Insert` and looking at inserting at several positions, but without luck.

Comment: you want Z1 or "Z1"?

Answer (score 7):

Using `MapIndexed[]`:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}};
MapIndexed[Prepend[#1, StringJoin["Z", ToString[First[#2]]]] &, list]
   {{"Z1", 1, 1}, {"Z2", 2, 1}, {"Z3", 3, 1}, {"Z4", 5, 1}, {"Z5", 1, 2},
    {"Z6", 2, 2}, {"Z7", 3, 2}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Flatten /@ Transpose[{"Z" <> ToString @ # & /@ Range@Length@list, list}]
```

> {{"Z1", 1, 1}, {"Z2", 2, 1}, {"Z3", 3, 1}, {"Z4", 5, 1}, {"Z5", 1,   2}, {"Z6", 2, 2}, {"Z7", 3, 2}}

Or

```
MapThread[Prepend, {list, "Z" <> ToString @ # & /@ Range@Length@list}]
```

Or

```
Join @@@ Transpose@{Array[{"Z" <> ToString @ #} &, {Length@list}], list}
```

Or

```
i = 1;
list /. {a__?NumberQ} :> {"Z" <> ToString[i++], a}
```

Or with `Insert`

```
Insert[list[[#]], "Z" <> ToString @ #, 1] & /@ Range@Length@list
```

Comment: Would be the the same coding

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a problem where `Table` provides a straight-forward solution.

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}};
Table[{"Z" <> ToString[i], Sequence @@ list[[i]]}, {i, Length[list]}]
```

> `{{"Z1", 1, 1}, {"Z2", 2, 1}, {"Z3", 3, 1}, {"Z4", 5, 1}, {"Z5", 1, 2}, 
>   {"Z6", 2, 2}, {"Z7", 3, 2}}`

Since `list` is a simple list of pairs, one might even consider

```
Table[{"Z" <> ToString[i], list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length[list]}]
```

Comment: Let's say i have a list = {x, 1 2 3}, {y, 4 5 6}. How do I add an element at the end of each {}. So the output would be: {x, 1 2 3, "element"}, {y, 4 5 6, "element"}

Comment: @Rob1234. This is an answer to what you asked. Why are you asking something different and unclear in a comment to my answer? That is not appropriate behavior on this site.